# SSL exceptions with existing certfiicates

Tags: java, ssl

Below is our code snippet to connect to a third party using SSL. Most of the solutions I found at SOF are for importing the certs to truststore, which I belive I am already doing as part of the below code. Nothing had changed and the certificate is still valid.

I had this code working until last week and now I am receving the below SSLHandShakeException. Any clues on what might have went wrong would be greatly appreciated.

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target

```
System.setProperties(newprops);
URL url = new URL(getURL());
File inFile = new File(FileLocation);
String path = inFile.getAbsolutePath();
System.out.print("Absolute Pathname "+ path);
KeyStore clientStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
clientStore.load(new FileInputStream(path), Password.toCharArray());
KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
kmf.init(clientStore, Password.toCharArray());
KeyManager[] kms = kmf.getKeyManagers();
SSLContext sslContext = null;
sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
sslContext.init(kms, null, new SecureRandom());             
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
System.out.print("connection "+ connection);

        //URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");
        connection.setConnectTimeout(getConnectionTimeout());
        connection.setReadTimeout(getReadTimeout());
        connection.connect();

        OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
        out.write(jsonObjectStr.toString());

        System.out.println("OutputStreamWriter : > " + out.toString());

        out.close();
```

Comment: have you imported third party certificate in jdk security ?

Comment: @Altmish-E-Azam I am already doing it as part of the code

Comment: Your code is using the default truststore without modification. The file you read is used as the SSL/TLS _keystore_, which contains (or should) the certificate and privatekey and probably chain _for the client to authenticate to the server_. That keystore is separate and different from the truststore which _may_ be in keystore format but contains the _CA and/or selfsigned_ cert(s) (_not_ client cert) used to verify the _server cert(s) to the client_, and about which your code does nothing at all. Check what cert chain the server is sending (with openssl s_client or probably more convenient ...

Comment: ... keytool -printcert -sslserver) and in particular what root or anchor it needs. Check what truststore your program is defaulting to; the usual one is JRE/lib/security/cacerts but there are other possibilities. Check whether the required root or anchor cert is in the truststore that is being used.